# KeyPressEvent getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i am using `KeyPress(object sender,KeyPressEventArgs e)` method it is displaying  the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'KeyPressEventArgs' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

What is the name space for it

Answer (score 3):

`KeyPressEventArgs` is a `Systems.Windows.Forms` class.  It's not intended for use in a web application - the web textbox control doesn't have this event (at least, on the server-side).

If you want to handle a keypress event in a webpage, you need to be doing this in Javascript (or equivalent) in the client's web browser.

Comment: @user1589801: if you google or even just search StackOverflow, you will find plenty of help in handling keypress events in web pages.  If you can't find something useful, come back and post another question on StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> **Add reference** and then select the dll which contain the keyPress class.

In the .cs file you are using the class, you need to import the referenced dll with using at the top of your file like this :

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Additionnaly, if your application is web-based, you will not be able to do this. Better for you to check some Javascript for this, take a look at the jQuery lib.